# BizTalk looking for wrong server for Bam Archive

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I have BizTalk 2013r2 environment with CU5 installed. If I load the Server Configuration UI and click in the "Bam Tools" left-hand option, it shows me that it's configured correctly for Bam Primary Import db, but has the wrong server name for Bam Archive.

The correct server name is BizTalkBuild01:

[image]

This prevents me from being able to deploy any Bam activities. It doesn't seem possible to correct this through the Server Configuration UI. Does anyone know of another way?

Comment: There is no error in the configuration wizard, so I assume the database actually exists?

Comment: Yes BAMArchive does exist on the other server but I need to use the one installed at BizTalkBuild01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that I assume your database already exists, try moving this database to the new server using the way described at MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561233(v=bts.20).aspx